# Is it possible to record a video while another video is being played in top most layer?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, avfoundation

I want to figure out if it is possible to record a video by accessing device camera through `AVFoundation framework` , while the other video is being played at the top layer through `MPMoviePlayerController`? 
I tried this thing , to add a view of `MPMoviePlayerController` on top of `VideoPreviewLayer` for `AVFoundation Framework`. But when I call the recording method I get the error saying : "The captured file cannot be written to the asset library.It is likely an audio-only file."

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. What you need to do is create the video preview layer like you did before. Then do the following:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player =
        [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
[self.view addSubview: player.view];
[player play];
```

This should put the `MPMoviePlayerController` above the video preview layer. If you are still getting an error then let me know in the comments, you might be doing something wrong with `AVFoundation`.